# How to change vector of physics body when tapping screen?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my game, once you tap the screen, the player starts to move to the right. If the screen is tapped again, the player moves downwards. Here is a little bit of code

```
 var isMoving = true

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {



    //moves to the right
    if isMoving == true  {
        player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 600.0 + playerSpeed, dy: 0)


    }
    //moves down
    else {

        player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -600.0 - playerSpeed)

    }

    isMoving = !isMoving

}
```

My problem here is that I want the player to change the direction from down to the left, then form left to right. So the sequence will be Right, Down, Left and Up. In other words, always make a right turn when screen is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to have a list of the different directions (vectors). You could keep an index and increase it at each tap, with a modulo of nDirections. Then you update the player direction.